# How can I Add css for product in shopping page which page is automatic created by woocommerce and that product is added by using product option

Tags: woocommerce

[I want to align the product block in center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX7pA.png)

[I inspect and do codding for css and successfully product block is aligned center.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg9k0.png)

But after refresh this design is gone. How can i add this css permanently and in which file I add these css??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the element lets only you to see the changes that you made temporarily, so after refreshing the page or closing it, the changes will be lost.
You have to post the changes you made in the website itself, so you can post it in the extra css area in the theme (if there is css area in the theme), or you can post it in the customizer, from the dashboard > appearance > customize > css
Then click publish.
Make sure to copy the class name of the element you want.